# Parsing HTML response in android

Tags: android, html-parsing

I need to know how can we parse a HTML value and fetch corresponding values from it.

Eg. http://pastebin.com/mNx2bDms . This is my HTML response from web service. I need to parse this html and get individual class values and save that to a string.

How can i do it?

Comment: try this one http://htmlparser.sourceforge.net/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make use of either HtmlCleaner or JSoup.

HtmlCleaner: http://htmlcleaner.sourceforge.net/

JSoup: http://jsoup.org/